# unset variable check in bash

Tags: bash, unset

I have two variables declared but unset:

```
__var1=
__var2=
```

Now I set `__var2` to have some value:

```
__var2=1
```

When I try to do a check like this:

```
[ -z "$__var1" -a -z "$__var2" ] || echo "Both missing!"
```

I am getting that message `Both missing!`. But that's **incorrect**.

Why is that? And how to do a proper check, to see if both of them are missing?

Comment: Starting in `bash` 4.2, you can use `-v` to test if a variable is set at all, whereas `-z` will be true if the variable is unset or set to the empty string: `-v __var1` (not there is no dollar sign; `-v` takes the name of a variable, not the string the variable expands to).

Comment: Good to know, however in my script, I did declare my vars, and just wanted to know if they were `__var1=` or `__var1=something`.

Comment: Isn't it strange however, that they are considered set just by declaring them?

Comment: You don't declare variables in shell. Assigning a value to a name (and `var=` and `var=""` are equivalent; the both assign the empty string to `var`) which isn't set makes it a set variable. Put another way, there is no such thing in shell as a variable without a value.

Comment: `foo=; [[ -v foo ]] && echo "foo is set"; [[ ! -v bar ]] && echo "bar is not set"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code prints "Both missing!" if it's not true (`||`) that both (`-a`) variables are empty (`-z`). You want to print the message if that IS true. Do that like this:

```
[ -z "$__var1" -a -z "$__var2" ] && echo "Both missing!"
```

I don't recall ever seeing a version of bash or test (what sh uses to evaluate the same expressions) without `-z` or `-a`, so as far as I know the above will work on any Unix-like system you're likely to find.

Comment: I must be too tired, missing these kind of things :)

Comment: Re `-a` and `-o`: POSIX does _allow_ their use, but issues the following _warning_ (http://man.cx/test) - emphasis mine: "Scripts should be careful when dealing with user-supplied input that could be confused with primaries and operators. Unless the application writer knows all the cases that produce input to the script, invocations like:

`test "$1" -a "$2"`

should be written as:

`test "$1" && test "$2"`

to avoid problems if a user supplied values such as $1 set to ’!’ and $2 set to the null string. [...] **where maximal portability is of concern [...] [use]
`test expr1 && test expr2`**"

Answer (score 6):

And if the user wants to check if the variable is really unset and not just having an empty value, you can do:

```
$ A=1234
$ [[ -z ${A+.} ]] && echo "Variable is unset."
$ A=
$ [[ -z ${A+.} ]] && echo "Variable is unset."
$ unset A
$ [[ -z ${A+.} ]] && echo "Variable is unset."
Variable is unset.
```

In which in your case it could be

```
[[ -z ${__var1+.} && -z ${__var2+.} ]] && echo "Both variables are unset!"
```

Comment: The `${var+something}` format expands to `something` when `var` is a set variable, or else nothing if not. You can try playing it around with `echo`.

Comment: So it is considered to be set even if you do `variable=`?

Comment: The above answer is the correct one. `[ -z "${A+.}" ]` is true if A is unset.  Note this uses `-` and not `:-` to test for unsetness but not emptyness.  ${A+.} means substitute an "alternate" value of "." if A is not unset.   See the bash man page and search for "Omitting the colon"

Answer (score 3):

[@Dave Schweissguth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728519/45375) makes a good point about the *logic* of your code, but there are also things to observe about the *syntax*:

- [***Update**: The original form of the question used assignments such as `$__var1=` - this has since been corrected*] In Bourne-like/POSIX-compatible shells you **do *not* use the `$` prefix when *assigning* a value**, only when *referencing* it; thus, your assignments should read:

```sh
__var1=
__var2= # or, later: __var2=1
```

- Your question is tagged `bash`, so the **best bash way** to write your could would be:

```sh
[[ -z $__var1 && -z $__var2 ]] && echo "Both missing!"
```

Note the use of `[[ ... ]]` rater than `[ ... ]`, which obviates the need to double-quote the operands to `-z`.

- By contrast, the **most portable** (POSIX-compliant) way is:

```sh
[ -z "$__var1" ] && [ -z "$__var2" ] && echo "Both missing!"
```

Comment: So in `[[` the unset variable is automatically substituted for something, so that `-z` unary operator doesn't lose it's operand?

Comment: @branquito: Yes, that's one of the advantages of using `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: I suppose it becomes `""` in that case?

Comment: @branquito: Loosely speaking, yes. More accurately, `[[ ... ]]` conditionals are parsed _differently_ than `[ ... ]` and its equivalent, `test`: The latter are parsed like command lines, whereas `[[ ... ]]` is parsed more like in traditional programming languages: instead of expanding `$__var1` _first_, and then evaluating the _result_ (as with `[ ... ]` / `test`), the expression is parsed _in one pass_, so `bash` knows that there _is_ an operand there, even if undefined or empty. (This is somewhat speculative, but I hope it's close enough to the truth - and relying on it works in practice.)

Comment: A little surprising but is `-a` not POSIX compliant? Well said about `[[ ]]` btw.

Comment: @konsolebox: `-a` and `-o` are _compliant_, but have _pitfalls_ - see my comment on @Dave Schweisguth's answer.

Comment: Oh but I disagree with that post. The problem with `test "$1" -a "$2"` is not the use of `-a`. The proper way is to do `test -n "$1" -a -n "$2"`. A lot of folks do `[ "$var" ]` to do shortcut with testing if a variable is empty or not but it's really a wrong practice.

Comment: @konsolebox: While `-n` and `-z` is the conceptually more explicit approach, _generally_ there's nothing wrong with `test "$var"` / `[ "$var" ]` to test for unset/empty variables. You're right: using `-n` with `-a` would avoid the quoted problems, but note how even the quoted _POSIX man page for `test` itself_ references the shortcut practice and, instead of criticizing it, advises against use of `-a` and `-o` instead.

Comment: @konsolebox: With respect to _maximum portability_: POSIX mentions that `-a` and `-o` are only supported on _XSI-conformant_ systems (XSI = X/Open System Interface Extension; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap02.html#tag_02_01_04). Thus, there may be POSIX systems that do NOT support `-a` and `-o`. Whether such systems are actually still around, I don't now.

Comment: @konsolebox: To summarize: If (a) you know that all platforms you need to support are XSI-conformant AND (b) you alway use `-n` to test for nonempty strings AND (c) you keep in mind that `-a` has higher precedence than `-o` (unlike `&&` and `||`, which have _equal_ precedence), then it's fine to use `-a` and `-o`.

Comment: @mklement0 I'd acknowledge that POSIX may have missed that but most shells even older than POSIX standard already supports `-a` and `-o`. `ash` suppports it, `jsh`/`heirloom-sh` supports it;`dash` supports it. I no longer see that old `sh` manual but I coded once in that very old shell and probably it supports it as well. These stuffs about POSIX and XSI, etc. are not necessary really when you're really seeking compatibility. Perhaps even just referring to shells like `heirloom-sh` would do. You have a point about considering precedence however the problem with && is that you can't group them.

Comment: Back then I was wrong about this but even the form `[ ]` supports stuffs like `[ \( -n a -o -n b \) -a \( -z '' \) ] && echo a` which probably would require subshells `()` with `&&` and `||` if you'd need to group them. Another way is to use `{ }` but it requires semicolons to end the group which may be ugly.